# Logging progress of `enumerate` function in Python

Tags: python, function, logging, python-2.x, enumerate

I am working on optimizing a Python (version 2.7; constrained due to old modules I need to use) script that is running on AWS and trying to identify exactly how many resources I need in the environment I am building. In order to do so, I am logging quite a bit of information to the console when the script runs and benchmarking different resource configurations.

One of the bottlenecks is a list with 32,000 items that runs through the Python `enumerate` function. This takes quite a while to run and my script is blind to its progress until it finishes. I assume enumerate is looping through the items in some fashion so thought I could inject logging or printing within that loop. I know this is 'hacky' but it will work fine for me for now since it is temporary while I run tests.

I can't find where the function runs from (I did find an Enumerate class in the `numba` module. I tried printing in there and it did not work). I know it is part of the `__builtin__ module` and am having trouble tracking that down as well and tried several techniques to find its exact location such as printing `__builtin__.__file__` but to no avail.

My question is, a) can you all help me identify where the function lives and if this is a good approach? or b) if there is a better approach for this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `enumerate` - as many of the `__builtin__` functions - is possibly written in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use tqdm module. [tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/)

tqdm module is used for visualization of the progress of an enumeration. It works with iterables (length known or unknown).

By extending tqdm class you can log required information after any required number of iterations. You can find more information in the tqdm class docstring.

Comment: This looks like a great solution. I found additional information here (specifically pertaining to enumerate) if you'd like to add to your answer: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/157

Comment: I'm using enumerate(tqdm(list)) in my function and it initiates the progress bar but doesn't actually show the progress.

Comment: Is you script still working as required without updating the progress?

Comment: It just shows the progress bar at 0% and hangs there so it is hard to tell. As mentioned, this enumerate function takes quite a while to work through so I would have to leave it running for a while in order to even see if it is working correctly. I have it running now and can report back but regardless it does not appear to be showing the progress correctly.

Comment: May be you can skip actual processing in the loop, and just test by printing the values that you are enumerating. If the values are enumerated correctly, and the progress is updated then you can put to the actual processing without worrying

Comment: Yes great thought. The issue is the size of the arrays and it looks like Python has to load the whole array up before enumerating. Your answer is correct but isn't working for what I'm doing. I abandoned the enumerate function is this instance and built a for loop around the length of the array. May run slightly slower than enumerate overall but allows me to log progress along the way.